# What is Krsna Paksh( Darkness) & Sukla Paksh(Brightness) in Bhagavad Gita?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, bhagavad-gita, upanishads

This two term Krsna Paksh( Path of Darkness) and Sukla Paksh(Path of Brightness) are mentioned in Bhagvad-Gita,

**Here is Sloka**

> **śukla-kṛṣṇe gatī hyete jagataḥ śāśvate mate |**
>
> **ekayā yāty-anāvṛtim anyāyāvartate punaḥ || 8.26 ||**

meaning

> These two paths, the bright and the dark, are said to be everlasting. By the former, one attains
> the state of non-return, by the other, one returns again.

Is there any other scripture which is mentioned and elaborate this term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As, We know in Bhagvad-Gita Lord Himself declare the two path. when soul will leave his body,then by his/her fortune or arrangement of god, it will pass aways through either Sukla Paksh ( Bright) or Krsna Paksh ( Dark).

**This is described Lord Himself in Bhagavad Gita in this two Sloka,**

**(1) "Paht of Light"**

> **agnir-jyotir-ahaḥ śuklaḥ ṣaṇmāsā uttarāyaṇam |**
>
> **tatra prayātā gacchanti brahma brahma-vido janāḥ || 8.24 ||**

meaning

> Light in the form of fire, the day, the bright fortnight, the six months of the northern course
> of the sun — the knowers of Brahman who take this path go to the Brahman.

**and (2) is "Path of Darkness":**

> **dhūmo rātris-tathā kṛṣṇaḥ ṣaṇmāsā dakṣiṇāyanam |**
>
> **tatra cāndramasaṃ jyotir-yogī prāpya nivartate || 8.25 ||**

meaning

> Smoke, night, the dark fortnight, the six months of the southern course of the sun — the Yogi
> who takes this path reaches the light of the moon and returns.

In the Vedas both the bright and dark paths are said to be everlasting in
relation to both the enlightened ones and those who simply do various good deeds.

**In Prasna Upanisad Sloka 9 & 10**

**Krsna Paksh**

> **sa.nvatsaro vai prajaapatistasyaayane dakshinam chottaram cha | tadye ha vai tadishhtaapuurte kritamityupaasate te chaandramasameva lokamabhijayante | ta eva punaraavartante tasmaadeta rishhayah prajaakaamaa dakshinam pratipadyante |  eshha ha vai rayiryah pitriyaanah || 9||**

Meaning

**Path of Darkness**

> The year is indeed Prajapati  and there arc two paths thereof: the Southern and the Northern. Those who follow  the path of Karma alone by the performance of sacrificial and pious acts obtain  only the World of the Moon and certainly they do return. Therefore those sages who  desire offspring travel by the Southern Path. The matter (Rayi) is verily the  path of the Forefathers.

**and Sloka 10**

**Sukla Paksh**

> **athottarena tapasaa brahmacharyena shraddhayaa vidyayaa.a. atmaanamanvishhyaadityamabhijayante| etadvai praanaanaamaa yatanametad amritamabhayametat.h paraayanametasmaanna punaraavartanta ityeshha nirodhastadeshha shlokah || 10||**

Meaning

**Path of Brightness**

> But those who seek the Self  through austerity, chastity, faith and knowledge, travel by the Northern Path  and gain the Sun. The Sun, verily, is the goal of all living creatures, the Immortal,  the Fearless; this is the final goal. From there they do not return, for, this  is the end. For this there is a mantra.

**The Chāṇḍogya Upaniṣad V.X.I-III states:**

**Path of Brightness**

> Those who know this and those who worship with faith, meditate in the forest etc., they
> go to the light’. (Chan. Up., 5.10.1),

and

**Path of Darkness**

> ’But those who in the village perform Vedic and secular acts of a meritorious nature and the giving of alms — they pass to the smoke’. (ibid., 5.10.3).**